# How to get all the results from a YQL query?

Tags: yahoo, yql

How do you get all the results from a YQL query?

I've already tried setting the limit to 0. it doesn't output any result. If I set it to say 50 I'm getting 50.

I'm using this for collecting questions from yahoo answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved my problem. didn't realise that yahoo answers can return a maximum of 50 results in a single resultset. but one can set the 'start' parameter of the query, iteratively to a maximum of 1000 to get more results.